# Export only visible entries of sparse tree

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm trying to export an org file into a file that contains only the visible entries (and parents) of a sparse tree (matching a specific tag).

For example, applying this to the following tree

```
* A
  Some content at level 0
** A1 :matchthis:
   Some content at level 1
** A2
* B
  Some content at level 0
```

matching the tag `matchthis` should produce the same result as exporting the tree:

```
* A
  Some content at level 0
** A1 :matchthis:
   Some content at level 1
```

If I export everything (in PDF, or txt), then the top level headlines (`B`) are also visible and therefore always included.

I don't see a way to export an org-file to an org-file with only the matched entries, which could be an acceptable intermediate step.

Answer (score 2):

As the built-int sparse tree has some limitations I've made a custom sparse tree function. I think with this function you can do what you want.

First it makes the sparse tree, then it hides everything (this is needed as the sparse tree function calls `org-overview` which reveals all level 1 headings) to reveal only the matches and the parents. You can optionally also show the body of the matches and/or the parents.

For your example

- call it with `(my-org-custom-sparse-tree nil "matchthis" t t)` to create the sparse tree
- and then use `(org-org-export-as-org nil nil t t)` to export the visible part to an org buffer.

*Note: This only works if `org-highlight-sparse-tree-matches` is set to `t` (it's the default) as the functions relies on the `org-occur-highlights`.*

```lisp
(defun my-org-custom-sparse-tree (todo-only match &optional
                                            match-body parents-body)
  "Create a custom sparse tree that only shows matched headings and parents.
For TODO-ONLY and MATCH see `org-match-sparse-tree'.
If MATCH-BODY is non-nil the bodies of the matches are shown.
If PARENTS-BODY is non-nil the bodies of the parents are shown."
  ;; Create the sparse tree.
  (org-match-sparse-tree todo-only match)
  (let ((pt-first (save-excursion
                    (org-first-headline-recenter)
                    (point)))
        (hls org-occur-highlights))
    ;; Hide everything.
    (outline-flag-region pt-first (point-max) t)
    ;; For each occur highlight overlay (the matches).
    (dolist (hl hls)
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (overlay-start hl))
        ;; Unhide match.
        (outline-show-heading)
        (when match-body (outline-show-entry))
        ;; Unhide parents.
        (while (org-up-heading-safe)
          (outline-show-heading)
          (when parents-body (outline-show-entry))))))
  ;; Hide all archived subtrees again.
  (org-hide-archived-subtrees (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Comment: I need this feature, but this function is not work fine for me.thx

Comment: @driftcrow Can you let me know, what is not working fine so I can adapt the function if needed? How are you calling the function (parameters)? The function from my answer has been working for me so far.

Comment: @Hubsian I trace to function, after eval (org-match-sparse-tree todo-only match) ,the value of org-occur-highlights is nil, so after  eval this function , all nodes has be hided.

Comment: @driftcrow hmm, does calling the built-in `org-match-sparse-tree` with your match work? what are u using as match? see [org-manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html)

Comment: It is work fine now ,thanks @Hubisan . cause  I use doom-config as my base config, for void org-indent-mode conflict , doom add a sentence   (setq org-highlight-sparse-tree-matches nil)  in hook ,so org-occur-highlights is nil